# Excel VBA - Copy and Paste two columns from one workbook into another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba. But, I have a big problem we're trying to solve at work. We receive payments for services that come through a commuter pretax deduction program. This is usually around 160+ payments that we have to enter into three systems. I've built a spreadsheet that cuts down on errors when we enter deposits. But, I'm trying to import the payments from the commuter program into my spreadsheet to cut out about an hour(or two) of data entry. The spreadsheet that I'm trying to import it to is an excel table. I'm trying to copy and paste two columns. I would like column D(Account #'s) in the "WAGEWORKS IMPORT" spreadsheet to only copy the used cells in column G and paste them into the active workbook in column B, and, copy the used cells in Column D($ Amt. of Payments) and paste them into the active workbook in Column I(The active workbook is ThisWorkbook-the bookkeeper will use a command button that I will assign later after I perfect the code) I can only get it to copy the cells from column G and copy them into the cells in Column B. The cells from Column D are getting pasted into column I, however they are doing so at the end of the table which is 600+ rows below where I need them. I need the corresponding payments to match the account numbers in the same row. My code is below. Can anyone help?

```
Sub Wageworks_Import()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long


Set x = Workbooks.Open("J:\Accounting - Copy\Accounting Projects\Wageworks Import\WAGEWORKS IMPORT.xlsx")

Workbooks.Open("J:\Accounting - Copy\Accounting Projects\Wageworks Import\WAGEWORKS IMPORT.xlsx").Activate


Sheets("index").Range("G10:G100").Copy


ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("ENTRY").Select
Set lastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
If IsEmpty(lastCell.Value) Then
  Set lastCell = lastCell.End(xlUp)
End If
lastrow = lastCell.Row + 1
Range("B" & lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Workbooks.Open("J:\Accounting - Copy\Accounting Projects\Wageworks Import\WAGEWORKS IMPORT.xlsx").Activate


Sheets("index").Range("D10:D100").Copy

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("ENTRY").Select
Set lastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)
If IsEmpty(lastCell.Value) Then
  Set lastCell = lastCell.End(xlUp)
End If
lastrow = lastCell.Row + 1
Range("I" & lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet1.Columns.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the same you do, but shorter and more efficient. It will paste the data always into the same rows.

```
    Sub Wageworks_Import()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lrM, lrF, erow As Long
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sht, sht2 As Worksheet

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("J:\Accounting - Copy\Accounting Projects\Wageworks Import\WAGEWORKS IMPORT.xlsx")
Set sht = wbk.Worksheets("index")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ENTRY")

lrF = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
lrM = sht2.Range("B:B").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

sht.Range(Cells(10, 7), Cells(lrF, 7)).Copy _
Destination:=sht2.Range("B" & lrM + 1)

sht.Range(Cells(10, 4), Cells(lrF, 4)).Copy _
Destination:=sht2.Range("I" & lrM + 1)

Application.CutCopyMode = False
sht2.Columns.AutoFit

wbk.Close saveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a good one UGP. Thanks for that. But, it is still identifying the last used cell in the destination sheet as below the table. Can it be modified to paste the data inside the table below the last used row?

Comment: What kind of table is it? i dont know why its thinking that something is in the cell where the table ends.

Comment: It's an Excel Table(built from the ribbon icon in the "Styles" on the home tab) in  that we repopulate with new deposits data every month. There are some VLOOKUP formulas and other formulas in each row(not where we're trying to paste). Do you think that the formulas could be causing it to skip to the end of the table? That's why I have the If/Then statements in my original macro. That seemed to work in column B. But, when it went to paste in column I. The data would paste after the end of the table That's why I got stuck I'm just not sure how to write that command in there using your variables

Comment: Ok now it got your question. Try this version.

Comment: Hey UGP. There was nothing in here. Did you leave it out?

Comment: The code in my answer, i changed the way it looks for the last row.